# Нахождение координат вершин прямоугольника

Tags: математика, геометрия

Не могу составить алгоритм нахождения координат вершин прямоугольника с такими известными переменными как **длины ребер**, **координаты одной вершины** в декартовой системе координат, **угол вращения** локальной системы координат прямоугольника.

К примеру:

- **a** и **b** - длины ребер прямоугольника;
- **A0(x,y)** - координата вершины прямоугольника, и она представлена центром локальной системы координат прямоугольника;
- **angle** - угол вращения локальной системы координат прямоугольника.

Не получается найти координаты **A1, A2, A3**.

Comment: Уточните - вращения именно системы координат? Или прямоугольника, повернутого на угол в этой системе координат?

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот вопрос относится к программированию и системному администрированию?

Comment: Harry, спасибо за замечание и прошу прощение за свой недочет в описании вопроса. Угол вращения локальной системы координат прямоугольника.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, как я понял задачу. Есть обычная декартова система координат, прямоугольник, стороны a и b, одна его точка, и он повернут относительно этой точки на угол.

Вопрос в том, как он располагался ранее, что за длины a и b.

```
  A3
  -------a------<- A2
  |            |
  b            |
  |            |
  --------------
  ^            ^
  A0           A1
```

Если представить картину таким образом, то все предельно просто. `A0`, естественно, остается на месте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если это то, что нужно вам. Но в общем случае прямоугольник-то уже мог быть изначально ориентирован как угодно. Вам нужно четко ставить задачу - даже для самого себя, а иначе получается "мне надо что-то посчитать!" - "ну возьмите какие-нибудь формулы..."

Comment: Последний абзац не совсем понятен. ИМХО проблема/задача ТС сформулирована достаточно ясно - есть длины ребер, угол и координаты 1 точки.

Comment: @Kromster И что? Представим, что `a` - по вертикали, `b` - по горизонтали. Формулы уже другие. И вообще - прямоугольник по определению - это просто все углы прямые, а не стороны вертикальны и горизонтальны! Вершина может быть любой из четырех! Не задается прямоугольник однозначно 4 числами ну никак... Если б он задал координаты трех вершин - да, дело другое.

Comment: Я бы все же заменил слово в последнем абзаце "повернут" на "ориентирован горизонтально или вертикально в положительном или отрицательном направлении осей", чтобы не было перекликания с вращением.

Comment: @Kromster Логично, спасибо.